# UnityWebRequest cannot receive data in some urls response

Tags: unity-game-engine, web, unitywebrequest

I have some problems with `UnityWebRequest`.

I have several URLs to communicating with my server.
Some URLs working fine expectly and other few URLs not working expectly.

It's a weird thing that there is no error in any unity and my server. My server respond with status 200 normally, but Unity client cannot receive any data from the server. (And later showed unity editor curl error 42 callback aborted in console) So I had testing my server on POSTMAN, Restlet Client, Curl, and even testing Axios on javascript. and it's working perfectly.
and I think response data size does not matter about this problem because other working URLs data is the much bigger than response data size

I don't know why UnityWebRequest cannot receive any data in some URLs responses.

My web server using spring framework and unity client version is 2019.2.12f1 and I tried 2019.3.0.f1 but it's not working too.

I think there is no matter about the server because the server respond with 200 and done with communication.

Thanks for reading my problem and please give me some advice about solving this problem.

UPDATE:

here is my request code

```csharp
private IEnumerator SendPutRequest() {
    var req = new UnityWebRequest("not/wokring/uri") {
        downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer(),
        uploadHandler = new             UploadHandlerRaw(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody)) {
                    contentType = "application/json"
                }
            };
    req.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "ACCESS TOKEN");
    req.method = UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbPUT;

    yield return req.SendWebRequest();

    Logger.Debug(this, req.downloadHandler.text);
}
```

UPDATE2:

Here is test calling other api (https://randomuser.me/api/)

```csharp
    private IEnumerator SendTestRequest() {
            var req = new UnityWebRequest("https://randomuser.me/api/") {
                downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer()
            };
            req.method = UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbGET;

            yield return req.SendWebRequest();

            Logger.Debug(this, req.downloadHandler.text);
        }
```

and working fine [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlzDK.png)

and not working request

here is request body json

```json
[{'complex-data'}]
```

here is code

```csharp
private IEnumerator SendBookResult() {
            var req = new UnityWebRequest("http://not/wokring/uri") {
                downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer(),
                uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bookSolveBody)) {
                    contentType = "application/json"
                }
            };
            req.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", Token);
            req.method = UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbPUT;

            yield return req.SendWebRequest();

            Logger.Debug(this, req.downloadHandler.text);
}
```

and here is respond server logs

```
    2021-03-30 15:52:01.768 DEBUG [user-resource-service,141475988d7477c7,835066c63711dc29,true] 40897 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [9651973a-15] Completed 200 OK
```

Their is no result and get error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuNzg.png)

and working url..

code

```csharp
private IEnumerator SendBookProblems() {
            var req = new UnityWebRequest("http://wokring/uri") {downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer()};
            req.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", Token);
            req.method = UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbGET;
            yield return req.SendWebRequest();
            Debug.Log(req.downloadHandler.text);
}
```

result is working

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbwAw.png)

Comment: Can you post your UnityWebRequest code here? and also your url so that we can replicate the issue.

Comment: @ArtZolinaIII update request code, and i use my server on localhost so did you need my url? when i change url another ex (a/b) there is not working too

Comment: Is this working on other server except your localhost?

Comment: Yes, It's perfectly working code even other URLs or other server in localhost, I'll update request body and postman result

Comment: Why don't you use UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbGET? is you want to grab data from server?

Comment: My restful API Server using specific http method. GET cannot accept my server and i tried to change put to post or post to put, but it's not working too..

Comment: You have check is other server has CORS configuration in it?

Comment: Yes. I tried to request with disable cors but, it still not working..

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution to my problem.

Just add these codes after create unity web request instance

```csharp
req.chunkedTransfer = false;
req.useHttpContinue = false;
```

I don't know why it works after adding these codes.

However, I figured out to working expectly.

Comment: `chunkedTransfer` by default is `false`.